# list separated by comma, but the last item must not have a comma

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

In laravel how do i separate each category with a comma,  if there are many categories, the last item shouldnt have comma. . .

it should look like:

Job categories:  category1, category2, category3, category4

Here is my code:

```
@if(count($job->categories) < 2)
     @foreach($job->categories as $category)
         {{ $category->name }}
     @endforeach
@else
     @foreach($job->categories as $category)
         {{ $category->name . ", " }}
     @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: @Uchiha He only wants to list the names of the categories.

Comment: Ohh my bad I didn't check that @Amarnasan

Comment: `echo implode(',',array_map(function($v){return $v->name;},$job->categories));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
implode(',', array_map(function($a){return $a['name'];}, $job->categories->toArray()))
```

You want all the names in an array, in order to implode them with a comma. So you iterate the categories with `array_map`. But `array_map` needs an array, not a `Collection`, so you first need to convert the categories `Collection` into an array with its `toArray` function.

But I think @CorradoStriuli answer is far more elegant and 'laravelish'.

Comment: @treb The answer of CorradoStriuli is FAR more elegant. I just updated it a bit to your requirements, but use it instead of mine by any means. Check it again, please.

Comment: @Amarnasan sir,... you know why corrados answer doesnt work? because its for array

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method 'lists' from Collection class. 
 More info at:
[Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_lists)

```
{{ implode(', ', $job->categories->lists('name')) }}
```

Comment: Change 'id' for 'name'.

Comment: will it be separated by comma?

Comment: No, but now that you have it as an array, you can perform an implode.

Comment: With the latests version of laravel you can do this:

 `{{ $job->categories->lists('name')->implode(',') }}`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `categories` is a `Collection` you can do that easily

```
{{ $job->categories->implode('name', ', ') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of way you could do that :

For example :

using `substr()` :

```
$yourString = susbtr($yourString,0,strlen($yourString-1));
```

using `trim()` :

`$yourString = trim($yourString,',');`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $job->categories is an array (and not something Iteratable), you could just use implode:

```
$yourString = implode(",",$job->categories);
//$yourString now contains a comma seperated list of categories
```

Or, doing it inside a twig template you can use join I believe (been a while since I used twig...)

```
{{ $job->categories|join(',') }}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html

Comment: BTW guys... my list isnt array, its a Collection... these things wont work